# Java.lang.verifyError when adding module to Android project

Tags: java, android, verifyerror

I'm adding a library to my project (a .aar) by using "Open module settings > new > Import .JAR/.AAR Package".

It builds correctly an the app opens but, when the first class of that library is being instantiated it gives me a "Java.lang.verifyError" with that class.

Reading about it it seems the error happens when the library used to compile is not the same as the one used at runtime. But that seems a little abstract to me, where can a I check if that happens? How should I correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your library modules use two version types of dependencies of same library types. Like, say you're using library A and B. Then A use support design 27 and B use 28. Make it same. Few days ago we faced this error by Java which is totally new to us. We were using library modules and after multiple research we found it and solved using same type of versions. I can't guarantee, it will work to you though.

Comment: Not exactly that, but it has led me to the solution, thanks :)

Comment: The problem actually causes for internal inconsistency. Here is the google documentation, https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/VerifyError